# vim surround extension install problems

Tags: vim, surround

I am trying to install the vim (7.4) surround extension on Arch Linux (downloaded and installed this week) within an Oracle VM on a Windows 7 host.

I am getting a variety of errors including E388 (Could not find definition) when on `"Hello World"` with my cursor inside the quotes I try:

```
:ds"
```

And E257 (cstag: tag not found) when on `<div>Hello World</div>` with my cursor inside the tags I try something like:

```
:cst<p>
```

I have downloaded the most recent version of vim surround from git

I have :set nocp

I have placed surround.vim in `~/.vim/plugin`

I have restarted vim

I have regenerated the helptags, and `:help surround` does work.

I extracted the files as the user running vim, there is no permission error.

Running `:scriptnames` shows `~/.vim/plugin/surround` in the list.

So as far as I can tell it is installed, just that it is not working.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surround is almost certainly working correctly, you just don't know how to use it and/or don't understand the difference between "Ex" commands and normal mode commands.

- `:ds` is the short form of `:dsplit`, see `:help :dsplit`.
- `:cst` is the short form of `:cstag`, see `:help :cstag`.

They are "Ex" commands, but Surround's `ds` and `cst` are not "Ex" commands: they are normal mode commands.

Instead of doing:

```
:ds"
:cst<p>
```

do:

```
ds"
cst<p>
```

And… Read The Fantastic Manual: `:help surround`.

Comment: Thanks, you were correct that I did not understand ex-mode.